# How to invoke Emacs from an Erlang escript?

Tags: emacs, erlang

Inspired by Git as when you type "git commit", it opens an Emacs or Vim session for you. I'm writing an Erlang escript, and I want it to open an Emacs session at the end of the execution of the escript. I've tried

```
os:cmd("emacs -nw file.txt")
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Evaluating the above command within the Erlang shell yields

```
"emacs: standard input is not a tty\n"
```

Comment: I don't know a solution to this but what about creating a bash wrapper and starting emacs after the escript finishes?

Comment: bash -c 'emacs -nw file.txt' to try bash wrapper

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to keep an Emacs running with [server mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) (put `(server-mode)` in your `~/.emacs`), and call `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` from Erlang.  That will open the file in the existing Emacs session.  `emacsclient` exits and returns control to your Erlang program once you hit `C-x #` in Emacs.